# Убрать opacity у дочерних div'ов?

Tags: opacity, html, css

У меня примерно такой код:

```
<div id="WWtray">
<div id="WWclock_val">
13:59
</div>
<div/>
```

Стили:

```
#WWtray{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 92%;
height: 35px;
border: 0px;
border-top: 1px solid #0099FF;
background-color: #66CCFF;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 1;
}
#WWclock_val{
position: absolute;
bottom: 17px;
right: 8px;
width: 60px;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 17px;
border: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #77CCFF;
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 2;
}
```

но у `#WWclock_val` всё равно opacity как у `#WWtray` а как принудительно заставить сделать 0.8 всё перепробовал ни чего не помогает
PS: Не предлагайте вынести `#WWclock_val` из под опеки `#WWtray` это не то что мне нужно

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Говорят RGBA помогает:

```
 #WWtray{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 92%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #0099FF;
    background-color: rgba(102, 204, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}
#WWclock_val{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 17px;
    right: 8px;
    width: 60px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 17px;
    border: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(119, 204, 255, 0.8);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[Полезная штука](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/)

Comment: Спасибо всё гуглил гуглил но нигде это не нашёл :)

Comment: Экслюзив :)

Comment: вау, классно! Даже @knes не знал о таком классном способе!