# Непонятное с z-index в CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть код, и почему-то z-index в нем не срабатывает, ничего не понимаю. 500 раз делал, работало. А тут нет? Я про opacity, почему он действует на всех, несмотря на z-индекс?:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <style>
        #body_st {
            background-color:#ff5c5c;
        }
        #div_bg_img {
            position:relative;
            background-color:#33CC99;
            width:100%;
            height:300px;
            opacity:0.5;
            z-index:0;
        }
        #div_st {
            position:relative;
            background-color:#ffCC99;
            font:normal 14px trebuchet MS;
            width:30%;
            border:thin #666666 solid;
            left:50px;
            z-index:2;
        }
    </style>
    <title>TiTLE</title>
</head>

<body id="body_st">
    <div id="div_bg_img">
        <center>
            <span style="font:bold 28px trebuchet MS; color:#FFff00;">SPAN на DIV-1</span>
        </center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div align="justify" id="div_st">DIV-2
            <br>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Что здесь не так? На других проектах я прописывал opacity на один какой-нибудь DIV и он прекрасно просвечивался, почему здесь так не срабатывает? Или для opacity нет понятия за или перед? И он тупо действует на всё?

Comment: Мои глаза!!! Откройте для себя такой сервис, как [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net), приведите примеры как должно быть и как есть, если хотите, чтобы шанс на ответ вас увеличился

Comment: Не понял? Offline редакторы уже устарели? На кой болт мне онлайн отладчик? Работу кода я и так вижу!
И вижу, что тут элемент с opacity действует и на другой. СТОП!
Он же в родительском DIVе! И его нужно или вытащить от туда или прописать ему opacity! Всё! дошло! теряю квалификацию :(

Comment: Нет, просто выташить из DIVa нужно.
прописание opacity в тот DIV ни чего не дало.

Comment: Онлайн-отладчик нужен не вам, а нам, чтобы не копипастить в редактор и все такое прочее. Имейте уважение к тем, кого просите о помощи.

Comment: ого, уже ctrl+C и ctrl+V устарело О_о!
Ясно... лень матушка... лень редактор завести, лень из буфера в него вставить...
Уходит время прикладного ПО с компиляторами и отладчиками... которых пока-что в онлайн не встречал...
З.Ы. про pastebin знал, а вот про ваш jsfiddle извините, один раз его юзал когда-то... думал для отладки.
Минусуйте, мне на онлайн статус как-то... я живу и работаю с реальными людьми!

Comment: Довели человека.

Comment: ВСЕ равно СПАСИБО ВСЕМ кто учавствовал :)
Самое главное, ведь это вы простимулировали шевеление уже закостенелых извилин.
И результат достигнут, всё работает и всё красиво и с opacity (пускай даже пока не RGBA) :)
ХэШКоТ РУЛИТ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я и говорю, я его вывел из того DIV'a, что был с opacity 0,5 и прописал ему свой opacity 0,7 и z-index'ы естественно сработали. А вот чтобы z-index'ы работали на DIV в DIV'e (типа дочернии) я пока кода не встречал.

Просто есть наследуемые свойства и это надо учитывать, z-index - работает внутри дива, также является наследуемым, но легко меняемым абсолютными значениями для всего документа. Opcity же свойство наследуемое и меняемое в диапазоне родительского дива. Собственно вот и все дела, а так я вообще ушёл от opacity - rgba - рулит, хотя IE и вякает своё непоследнее слово.

Comment: А минус за юзанье opacity? (Юрий Соснов - юзер с авторитетом +1)

Comment: вам же "на онлайн статус как-то...", дак в чем же проблема? Вам вряд ли дали именно минус за opacity.

Answer (score 3):

У меня была такая проблема: [Как убрать opacity у дочерних div'ов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84850/%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2). Поможет RGBA вместо Opacity.

Comment: Я и говорю, я его вывел из того DIV'a, что был с opacity 0,5 и прописал ему свой opacity 0,7 и z-index'ы естественно сработали. А вот чтобы z-index'ы работали на DIV в DIV'e (типа дочернии) я пока кода не встречал.