# Прозрачность родительского и дочерних элементов. Как ограничить распространение свойства?

Tags: opacity, css

В CSS прозрачность элемнта-родителя передается дочерним элементам: если некоторый элемент на странице имеет свойство opacity=.5, то даже при явно заданном opacity=1 [дочерние элементы будут полупрозрачными](http://jsfiddle.net/pLNgf/1/).

Решение - сделать непрозрачный родительский элемент, при этом один из дочерних элементов становится псевдо-родителем. Именно ему задается свойство полупрозрачности. Соответственно, [свойство не будет распространяться на другие вложенные элементы](http://jsfiddle.net/pLNgf/3/).

Есть ли варианты ограничить распространение свойство родителя на дочерние элементы без создания псевдо-родителя?

UPD. Нашлось еще одно решение - использовать псевдолементы (см. ответ ниже).

Comment: Откройте вопрос и я вам напишу ответ метод которым пользуюсь сам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть ли варианты ограничить распространение свойство родителя на дочерние элементы без создания псевдо-родителя?

Средствами CSS - нет. Это свойство наследуется всеми потомками.
Желаемого эффекта можно добиться путем позиционирования содержимого.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Позиционирование</title>
        <style type="text/css">
         section {
           position: relative;
           width: 500px;
           height: 300px;
         }
         article#Opacity {
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-color: #eee;
           filter:alpha(opacity=50);
           opacity:0.5;
         }
         article#content {
           width: 460px;
           position: absolute;
           left: 40px;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CSS Opacity</h1>
        <section>
            <article id="Opacity"></article>
            <article id="content">
              Содержимое без прозрачности.
            </article>
        </section>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, перед комментированием не посмотрел ссылку на jsfiddle.net. Там показано это же решение. Тогда остается актуальным только первая часть сообщения - штатными методами предотвратить наследование прозрачности не получится.

Comment: @iKozuko

>Средствами CSS - нет.

Будем спорить?

Comment: @Rulez
>Будем спорить?
Простите, о чем тут можно спорить ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Я задал вопрос:
[Убрать прозрачность у дочерних div'ов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84850/%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2)
Идеальным оказался вариант применения RGBA (Смотреть ответ @invincible)

Comment: Ну да. Видел ваше решение было с RGBA и еще одно аналогичное(вы свое удаляли, @zloctb оставил). Технически, правильный ответ дал @iKuzko. Если фон - цвет, то решение с RGBA идеально подходит (как более простое), но если используется фоновая картинка, то лучше все-таки псевдоэлементы.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в  сторону rgba .
Вот http://htmlbook.ru/blog/poluprozrachnyy-fon ,почитайте .

Comment: Замечательное решение, только вот оно к цветам применимо только. Насколько я понял, если в блоке фоновая картинка, то прием бесполезен.

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием псевдо-элементов:

HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Некоторый текст</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px; height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #000;
}
.parent:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}
.parent:hover:before{
  opacity: .5;
}
.child {
  margin: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроссбраузерно лучше использовать прозрачную картинку.