# [CSS3 : Opacity] : непрозрачное содержимое в полупрозрачном блоке

Tags: css3, opacity, css

**Здравствуйте!**

Скажите, а вообще возможно сделать так, чтобы на содержимое( текст, картинки, прочее ) не влияло свойство прозрачности( **Opacity** ) родительского блока?

Answer (score 4):

Вопросы такие уже были здесь:
 1. [Прозрачность родительского и дочерних элементов. Как ограничить распространение свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/122810/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) 
 2. [Убрать прозрачность у дочерних div'ов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84850/%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2)
Вывод: я считаю самый лучший вариант использование RGBA (Смотреть ответ @invincible по ссылке [#2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84850/%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Comment: @Rules, спасибо! Вторая ссылка и правда помогла! Классный кроссбраузерный способ! Даже @knes об этом не знал =)

Answer (score 1):

Нет.

Костылями можно. Фактически, это уже будет не родительский элемент, а просто нейкий элемент, лежащий ниже.

Comment: Да, вот только так и получается...

Answer (score 1):

На родительский блок вместо опасити, ставить пнг картинку бгшкой.

Comment: Ну, да. Но это тоже костыль. Только у меня "не родительский", а у вас - "не опасити"...
+

Comment: Не, это уж чересчур котыльно!