# Эффект стекла в CSS

Tags: html, css, эффекты

Возможно ли сделать вот такой эффект стекла через CSS?

[image]

у меня есть такая часть кода:

```
<div class='osnova'> <a href='..'>в траве сидел кузнечик..</a></div>
```

Если я у div увеличиваю прозрачность, то и текст тоже становится прозрачным, хоть в `<a>` я еще засовывал потом

```
opacity 1.0
```

Подскажите, как можно избежать того, чтобы текст становился прозрачным вместе с фоном?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я уже задавал похожий вопрос: [Убрать opacity у дочерних div'ов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84850/html-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2) Как сказал @invincible вам надо в opacity использовать не #RGB цвета а [RGBA](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/).
Например:

```
background-color: rgba(119, 204, 255, 0.8);
```

Comment: Только надо сделать поправку, что "счастливые" обладатели осла ниже девятой версии этого не увидят.

Comment: Спасибо! Это очень помогло!

Answer (score 5):

Прозрачность элемента распространяется на все его дочерние элементы. Поэтому вам надо создать еще обин блок, на который вы повесите прозрачность и поместить его под вашим блоком "osnova" слоем ниже.

[Смотреть пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/CadDM/1/)