# Генератор rgba

Tags: css

Есть ли какие нибудь генераторы, которые обычный формат цвета например `#ffffff`, переведут его в формат `rgba()` и ещё ко всему прочему полупрозрачным? Может кто нибудь из Вас знает?

Comment: "Обычный" формат -- это скорее всего rgb. Неужели вы не справитесь с добавлением одного байта (a) самостоятельно? Задача нигде не реализована ввиду её тривиальности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите.

```
function hex2rgb($hex) {
   $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

   if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
   } else {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
   }
   $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
   return 'rgba('.implode(",", $rgb).',.5)';
   // или вернуть значения массивом
   // return $rgb;
}

echo hex2rgb('#FFFFFF'); // rgba(255,255,255,.5)
echo hex2rgb('#036'); // rgba(0,51,102,.5)
```

Comment: Не за что )

Кстати, если RGB будет в полном формате (#FFFFFF), а не сокращенном (#FFF), то можно еще короче:

    $rgb_color = array_map('hexdec', str_split(str_replace('#', '', '#FFFFFF'), 2));
    echo 'rgba('.implode(',',$rgb_color).',.5)'; // rgba(255,255,255,.5)

Answer (score 0):

Я задал вопрос:
[Убрать прозрачность у дочерних div'ов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84850/%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2)
Идеальным оказался вариант применения RGBA (Смотреть ответ @invincible)

И там была ссылка на [генератор RGBA](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/)